# What is the main difference between instances and sub-classes?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

This question is about **Ontologies** , I am implementing an ontology about potential physical attacks on wireless sensors as devices.

I created class **Modification_Attack** meaning attacks which modify in the sensor itself. I created **Programming_Modification** as an instance of this class, is this logical, is it better a sub-class or neither an instance nor a sub-class?

Answer (score 5):

> What is the main difference between instances and sub-classes?

This question isn't really unique to OWL ontologies;  it comes up in object-oriented programming, and in set theory in mathematics.  A class is a collection of its members.  E.g.,

**Person ≡ { person<sub>1</sub>, person<sub>2</sub>, … }**

Suppose you have another class:

**TallPerson ≡ { person<sub>63</sub>, person<sub>102</sub>, … }**

A class A is a subclass of the class B if every element of A is also an element of B:

(A ⊆ B) ≡ (x ∈ A → x ∈ B)

So, for instance, if every member of **TallPerson** is also a member of **Person**, then **TallPerson** is a subclass of **Person**.

> I created class Modification_Attack meaning attacks which modify in
>   the sensor itself.I created Programming_Modification as an instance of
>   this class , is this logical , is it better a sub-class or neither an
>   instance nor a sub-class?

This is a choice that you need to make.  It really depends on the context and how you intend to use the ontology.  If you're observing attacks in the wild and trying to categorize them, you probably want a subclass, but you'll want to have *instances* of **Programming_Modification**.  That is, you'll want something like:

**Programming_Modification ≡ { attack<sub>24</sub>, attack<sub>89</sub>, … }**

But if you've got some other kind of use case, where you you want to talk about **Programming_Modification** as a single entity, then it might make more sense for it to be an individual.

Comment: Everything is made a lot more complicated in OWL when you have the OWL 2 RDF-based semantics where a class is an **instance** of `owl:Class` and classes are not collections of things but things that are related to a collection of things...

Answer (score 1):

I have been thinking through the same issue. And I think the same thing can be both an instance and a subclass depending on whether you plan to use it conceptually or not, which can be simplified to whether you would describe it using *the* or *a*.

For example, I am working on a materials ontology, where the main class is `Material`. A particular type of material is `Steel`. If I say *the steel* then `steel` an *instance of* `Material`. If I say *a steel* then `Steel` is a *subclass of* `Material`. Further, `steel` is an *instance of* `Steel`. And it would be more appropriate to also give it some kind of meaningful identifier like `steel-1`.

It all seems to come down whether you are using a term as a conceptual class or as a name for some instance of that class. In your case, I think it would probably be more appropriate to say `Programming_Modification` is a *subclass* as you could probably have many of such modifications which you would refer to as *the* `first Programming_Modification` or *the* `second Programming_Modification` . Would love to see what you came up with though if you have a solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31361562)

Comment: The last paragraph is an answer. Data modeling is subject to interpretation and changes however, which is why the last sentence asks if they came up with a different solution.